# where function not working or responding with bool when string wanted - python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, where-clause

Could someone please explain how using the np.where I am suppose to get the string value instead of a False bool.
Or why this Where function with pandas doesn't seem to do anything.

```
 np.where(concat_df["match"] == True, concat_df["DBT_VALID_TO"] == concat_df["DBT_UPDATED_AT"].shift(1), concat_df["DBT_VALID_TO"] == 'error')

(concat_df["DBT_VALID_TO"] == 'NaN').where(concat_df["match"] == False, inplace=True)
```

This is the intended:

```
concat_df['match'] = concat_df["Site No"].eq(concat_df["Site No"].shift())
concat_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

for index, row in concat_df.iterrows():
    if row["match"] == True:
        row["new column"] = row["DBT_UPDATED_AT"].shift(1)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: np.where(<condition>, <if true do this>, <if  false do this>). You'd have to share more info such as raw data and desired output. Based off the looping and inplace=True I'd say there is a better way.

Comment: You need to reread your documentation for using `np.where`.  I could point you to the `numpy` docs, but I'm not sure that's what `pandas` users use.  Sometimes it seems to be an informal idea - "you should try np.where" to speed up your pandas iteration.

Comment: why do you use `==` in `np.where()` ?

Comment: it should be rather `row["new column"] = np.where(row['match'], row["DBT_UPDATED_AT"].shift(1), 'error')`

Comment: Please explain the requirement by showing an example (as simple as possible to illustrate the problem) of what could be in `concat_df` before the call, and what should be in it afterward.